# IE8 issues occurring on menu rollover

Tags: internet-explorer-8, rollover

I am having rollover issues on IE8 for boxes remaining after rolling off main top navgations:

http://www.conversantmedia.com/

above is my website, it was working fine a few months ago in IE8 and I have not adjusted anything in the main nav and cannot seem to figure out why this is happening using the IE debugger tools.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any problems with rolling off the main top navigations using IE 8.

Comment: Works good on IE 11 too

Comment: Yes sorry it was a CSS Pie code issue, thank you!!!